# How can user import images in app?

Tags: android, image, user-input

I would that when the user do a longPressClick on an imageview he can import an image. I know that i should use intents and this is not a problem, but how should i set the imageView? Should use inputeStream? 
I have seerched a tutorial but i found anything. So can someone advise me a good tutorial, or any tips? I don't have idea how should i do..
Thanks, and sorry for the bad english.

Here is my intent:

```
public class ImportImage {
View v;
public ImportImage(View v){
    this.v = v;
}

public void start(){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);




}
}
```

---

### UPADATE

I have serched on google with Gallery Intent and found the solution. Before have serched as "How can user import images in app". When i have finished my code i will post it, so if someone have my same problem can resolve.

Comment: import images from where? local storage? webservice?